# PHP Number Format (Currency)

Tags: php, numbers, currency, number-formatting

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my number format to display properly. The input comes from a user defined value on a search form, and is served to my results page. I'm seeing the following results.

> Input is 2000, output is $2.00
>   Input is 200, output is $2.00
>   Input is 50, output is $5.00

Can someone take a look at this code and see where I'm going astray?

```
<?php echo '$'.number_format($_POST["input_price"][0], 2, '.', ',').'';  ?>
```

Comment: The zeros are likely being cut off and the input is actually 2, 2, and 5. Your output is correct; it is the input that is wrong: http://codepad.org/Q4Qrdc5O

Comment: If I use only `<?php echo $_POST["input_price"]; ?>` the output number includes the 0's, however it doesn't include the currency symbol or commas... strange

Comment: Is `$_POST['input_price']` an array of prices, or just a single price? It would seem that it is a single price, and hence leading to what @MarkM has explained. (If you reference an index of a string like it were an array, you get the character at that position.) What does `var_dump($_POST['input_price'])` produce?

Comment: It's a single price selected from a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, see if removing the `[0]` works

```
<?php echo '$' . number_format($_POST["input_price"], 2, '.', ',');  ?>
```